# Using DebugDiag with an in-house application

Tags: windows, debugging, iis, debug-symbols

How do I use DebugDiag with an in-house application?

What do I need to do (include obj file, link to an assembly, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debugdiag Analysis requires symbols (By default the Microsoft public symbol server is already configured with Debugdiag). All downloaded Microsoft public symbols will be places in “c:\symcache”

If you have an in-house app, and you have symbols, then you can just add your PDB files (only) to the symbol path: “c:\symcache”

During debugging, if you are setting breakpoints, then you also need symbols added to the appropriate path. “c:\symcache”

[image: Image of dxdiag config]

Comment: One should mention that in a company it is useful to place the cache onto a share that everyone can write to.