# DebugDiag - Instrument stack like windbg 'kp' command

Tags: c#, c++, callstack, debugdiag

Is it possible to get the DebugDiag Analysis to provide stack trace info like the windbg 'kp' command ?
i.e. 'kp' has the source file path, line number and values of arguments
(i have confirmed that for a valid DMP that our symbol server correctly instruments the DMP in windbg)

Thanks

Comment: Did you add your symbols server into the search path -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888316/using-debugdiag-with-an-in-house-application ... also try out this script : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/puneetgupta/2010/05/13/debugdiag-script-to-load-all-symbols-in-a-dump-file/

Comment: I checked and the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH variable  was used (as in windbg) but the check partly solved the issue. It turns out that by default, source line info is unticked by default! It does not show stack argument values but it is better than before.

Answer (score 0):

I checked and the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH variable was used (as in windbg) but the check partly solved the issue. It turns out that by default, source line info is unticked by default! It does not show stack argument values but it is better than before.